# Can we @Override a public method of super class in the derived class?

Tags: java

Please see the code below for an example of my question:

```
    class Person  
    {  
        private  String name;  
        public  
            String toString()  
            {  
                return this.name;  
            }  
    }

    class Student extends Person  
    {  
       private  int no_of_courses;  
       public  
           @Override String toString()  {  return "Student " + super.toString();  }
    }  
    class SuperDemo  
    {  
        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {  
            Person p = new Student("ABC,"XYZ");  
            System.out.println(p.toString());  
        }  
    }
```

Can we Override a public method of a super class in the derived class?      The Person class has the Constructor:

`Person(String name)`

The Student class has the constructor:

`Student(String name)  { super(name); }`

Comment: Why don't you try it before posting a question?

Comment: Please put in a grain of effort if you're going to edit a question, this still looks horrible.

Comment: i tried it i'll add error code attempting to access weaker access privilages; was public

Comment: Yes you can override a super class method.!!make the Person class as public

Comment: Agreed. A minute in of test code could easily answer this question; why do you feel the need to make others do this for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**  You already do this naturally when overriding `toString()` from `Object`.

You cannot override:

- Anything marked `final`
- Anything `static`
- Anything `private`

You also cannot reduce the visibility of an overridden method; that is, you can't override a `public` method into a `protected` one.